# LibGDX. Box2d. Joint rotation or how to make a tank

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I trying to make a taknk with LibGDX and Box2D. There is a chassis and tower connected through the box2d revolute joint.

Chassis:

```
BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
bodyDef.bullet = true;

PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
shape.setAsBox(sizeM.x / 2, sizeM.y / 2);
FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
fixtureDef.shape = shape;
fixtureDef.density = MASS / (sizeM.x * sizeM.y);

Body body = world.createBody(bodyDefComponent.bodyDef);
body.createFixture(fixtureDef).setUserData(this);

body.setLinearDamping(DAMPING);
body.setAngularDamping(DAMPING);
```

Tower:

```
BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
bodyDef.bullet = true;
bodyDef.angularDamping = 3;

PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
shape.setAsBox(sizeM.x / 2, sizeM.y / 2);
FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
fixtureDef.shape = shape;
fixtureDef.density = MASS / (sizeM.x * sizeM.y);

Body body = world.createBody(bodyDefComponent.bodyDef);
body.createFixture(fixtureDef).setUserData(this);
```

Joint:

```
RevoluteJointDef jointDef = new RevoluteJointDef();
jointDef.enableMotor = true;
jointDef.maxMotorTorque = 10000;
jointDef.initialize(mChassis, mTower, new Vector2(position.x, position.y));
Joint joint = world.createJoint(jointDef);
```

Tower rotate method:

```
body.applyAngularImpulse(-ROTATION_POWER, true);
```

The chassis rotates in the same way as the tower. When chassis rotates, tower rotates too. It's ok. But if I rotating the tower, chassis rotates too. I also tryed to set infinity mass, bot that doesn't helps. I guess there is something wrong with the joints. Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps, they're colliding? Try to make tower to be a `sensor` to check it. Also, maybe because of `jointDef.enableMotor`?

Comment: They aren't collide because the had the same subzero filter:
fixtureDef.filter.groupIndex = id;
where id < 0.
I tryed to disable motor but tower still move the chassis.